# substring of a list from another list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like below

```
fulllist = ['item1 cost is 1', 'item2 cost is 2', 'bla bla bla', 'item3 cost is 3', 'item4 cost is 4', 'bla bla bla']
```

Another list with keywords

```
keywords = ['item1','item2','item4','item3']
```

I need to search fulllist with items of the keywords list and if the keyword is found as a substring from fulllist, I need that statement to be written to a new list in the same order as keywords list
like:

```
newlist = ['item1 cost is 1', 'item2 cost is 2', 'item4 cost is 4', 'item3 cost is 3']
```

I tried below piece of code:

```
fulllist = ['item1 cost is 1', 'item2 cost is 2', 'bla bla bla', 'item3 cost is 3', 'item4 cost is 4', 'bla bla bla']
keywords = ['item1','item2','item4','item3']

newlist = [fulllistitem for fulllistitem in fulllist for i in range(0,len(keywords)) if keywords[i] in fulllistitem]
```

but newlist is not in the matching order of keywords list but in fullist order, like

```
newlist = ['item1 cost is 1', 'item2 cost is 2', 'item3 cost is 3', 'item4 cost is 4']
```

instead of

```
newlist = ['item1 cost is 1', 'item2 cost is 2', 'item4 cost is 4', 'item3 cost is 3']
```

how to the list as intended?

Comment: First iterate over keywords list, then on fulllist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. It could be done like this, also there is no need to use range.

```
newlist = [item for keyword in keywords for item in fulllist if keyword in item]
```

Modified answer. That allows you to have 'dummy' objects in result list if there is no such object in `fulllist`

```
result = ['dummy'] * len(keywords)
for index, keyword in enumerate(keywords):
     for item in fulllist:
         if keyword in item:
            res[index] = item
```

Comment: I'm facing another issue, if the fulllist doesn't contain a keyword from keywords list, then the newlist item related to that is ignored, instead I need 'dummy' in its place. I tried the following method for this but output is not as intended. I tried: [fl if kw in fl else 'dummy' for kw in keywords for fl in fulllist], say my keywords list is changed with a string that doesn't exists in full list as, keywords = ['item1','item2','item10','item3']

Comment: Modified it a little

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution, using regex.

```
import re

join_ = "|".join(fulllist)

print([re.search(x + "[^|]+", join_).group() for x in keywords if x in join_])
```

---

```
['item1 cost is 1', 'item2 cost is 2', 'item4 cost is 4', 'item3 cost is 3']
```